# How are these different types of notation called?

Tags: calculus, notation

My teacher used to give questions on integrals of vector fields with different notation to get us used to seeing things in different forms. I'm just wondering what these three different forms of notation are called so I can look them up.

I've written down 3 equations for a vector field, which I think are equivalent.

$$F = 2i + 3j + 5k$$

$$F =\langle 2x, 3y, 5z \rangle$$

$$F(x, y, z) =\langle 2x, 3y, 5z \rangle$$

Comment: The last two need not have the variables of the unit vector in the angled brackets, the unit vector they correspond to is implied from the order they are written

Comment: Alternatively, the last 2 fields may not be equivalent to the first field, but the variables in the angled brackets *should* stay because the field is position dependent.  It could be that the first field was not written correctly and the second and third fields are correct.

Answer (score 1):

The first uses unit vectors. This is called 'unit vector notation'.

The second and third are the same notation, but the third is more explicit/unambiguous. The notation $(2x,3y,5z)$ or $\left( \begin{array}{c}2x\\3y\\5z\end{array}\right)$ is called 'matrix notation', because it's a matrix with respectively 1 row and 1 column.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_notation

Answer (score 0):

The third one is the better because it shows the dependency of $F$, and it shows clearly that $F$ is a function from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$, i.e. it associates a vector to each vector.